# Authenticate using OAuth Providers with Asp.net WebApi2 from Windows Phone 8 and Windows Store App

Tags: windows-phone-8, oauth-2.0, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library, asp.net-web-api2

**Setup :**

- ASP.Net WebApi2 Setup using Individual Template
- Windows Store App
- Windows Phone 8 App
- Portable Class Library for Api Consumption

The PCl encapsulates all the api calls so that both the store app and phone app can share the code. I am able to register and login using the local accounts. But i also need to be able to log the user in to the api via Facebook, Google etc. How do i put this in the PCL? I thought of using WebAuthenticationBroker but it seems it's not available in PCL.